# updating array in object properties using property's name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an object defined like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    lists: ["Dogs", "Cats"],
    items: {Dogs:[], Cats:[]}
    };
  }

  handleAddItem(item) {
    console.log(item);
  }
```

I have the variable

```
console.log(item);// output {Dogs:[{name: "lofi"}]}
```

I don't know how to verify which property is in the `item` (`Dogs` or `Cats`) so that I can update the object items{} to make it becоme in my example like this:

```
items{Dogs:[{name: "lofi"}], Cats:[]}
```

Comment: `items.Dogs.push({name: 'lofi'})`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, the item's value can change, instead of output {Dogs: [{name: "lofi"}]} it could be {Cats: [{name:"tom"}]}

Comment: @E.Mohammed: Please try out my solution and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const item = {Dogs:[{name: "lofi"}]}
let whichAnimal = Object.keys(item)[0]; //Dogs
let animalObj = item[whichAnimal][0]; //{name:'lofi'}

this.setState({ 
  items: this.state.items[whichAnimal].push(animalObj)
})
```

You can use `Object.keys` to get all the keys and assuming your `item` has only one variable at a time, we set with index 0. Storing it in a variable so that during `setState` we will know which array in exact we going to push the item into

Comment: Sorry to be late to answer, it's working using your suggestion but with a little modification, to get the animaleObj I didn't use the keys  `let animalObj = item[whichAnimal]; // {name: 'lofi'}` because there is only one object in it every time.

Comment: Its ok since StackOveflow is just a site to get the idea on achieving what you wanted to anyway. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

When you add "lofi" to items.Dogs, you should do like this:

```
this.state.items.Dogs.push({name:'lofi'})
```

The console output shows that you made the **Cats** disappear, so I wondered that you override the **items** state like:

```
this.state.items = {Dogs:[{name:'lofi'}]}
```

If I guess wrong, please let me know.

---

Edit:

Pass the values as parameter is like below:

**add category:**

```
var new_category = 'Birds';
this.state.items[new_category] = [];
```

**add item to category:**

```
var category = 'Birds';
var new_item = 'dori';
this.state.items[category].push({name: new_item });
```

Comment: But the items can change and I can have more than just Dogs and Cats, how I can access the items by the property that is the same in the item

Comment: If you want to have birds, do like so:
this.state.items.birds = [];
this.state.items.birds.push({name:'dori'});

Comment: Or you want to output only dogs, you can do like: console.log({Dogs: this.state.items.Dogs});

Comment: the items properties aren't predifiend, so I need a way to get the property's name of object as a variable that can change.

Answer (score 0):

Since, this is a react app you want to use `setstate`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            lists: ["Dogs", "Cats"],
            items: {Dogs:[], Cats:[]}
        };
    }

    handleAddItem(item) {
        console.log(item);
        var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.items));
        copy["Dogs"].push({name: "lofi"}];
        this.setState({items: copy});
    }
}
```

In react don't try to change the state directly. Also, its always a best practice to copy the object first because if you change the original state object it can make your app behave unpredictable.

Comment: Thank you, but the variable 'item' can have object with different property, I have to verify if the property in the 'item' is a `Dogs`  or `Cats`